# Uploaded the Android app to different enterprise publish sources. Uploading same app to Google play store gives error "package name already exists"

Tags: android, google-play, android-build, intune

I have uploaded my Android application with package name (for e.g. com.abc.xyz) to our Microsoft Intune store and now trying to upload the same application with same package name to Google play store. When I upload the build, it says "You need to use a different package name because com.abc.xyz already exists in Google play".

When I search the play store with com.abc.xyz package name, it says no applications found.

My question is if we upload an app through Intune store/App center, is it not allowed to upload to Google play store?

Please let me know if anybody faced the same problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Microsoft Intune store is using internally Google play store for publishing apps. So, if any app is uploaded in Intune, another app with same package name is not allowed for Google play store.